# How to sort friends by last message time like whatsapp

Tags: sql

I'm working on a chat app and I want to get a query that pulls out the list of friends and sorts them by last message time just the way whatsapp does its own.

Three tables in the database are important.

1. Table name: Users
   Purpose: It stores the list of all registered users in the chat app.
   Columns:- sn, matricno, fullname, password, faculty, department, level, year, study_centre, gender, email,phoneno and picture.
2. Table name: Friends 
   Purpose: It stores all the list of friends and friend requests.
   Columns:- sn, user1, user2, date_initiated,status(1=request sent, 2=they are friends, 3= They are no longer friends), date_accepted, date_unfriend
3. Table name: Messages
   Purpose:- It stores all the messages that have been sent between friends
   Columns:- sn, sender, recipient, content, date, mread(to indicate if the recipient has read the message)

So far, this query pulls the list of friends just the way I want, what is left is to combine the messages table and sort it using the date column

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE matricno IN (SELECT user2 
                   FROM friends 
                   WHERE user1 = 'NOU1213131415' 
                     AND STATUS = '2'  
UNION 
SELECT user1 
FROM friends 
WHERE user2 = 'NOU1213131415' 
  AND STATUS = '2')
```

The picture below is an example of the chat list it pulls out

[image: The picture below is an example of the chat list it pulls out]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the SQL dialect you use and didn't tested it, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.*, 
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM messages m WHERE m.sender = u.matricno OR m.recipient = u.matricno) AS max_date
FROM users u
JOIN friends f ON (u.matricno = f.user1 OR u.matricno = f.user2) AND f.status = 2
WHERE u.matricno = 'NOU1213131415'
```